# kubelet failed to pull image - x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to install Kubernetes 1.9.0 on a cluster of CentOS 7.3 systems running in VMware Workstation on Windows 7, following the "kubernetes-the-hard-way tutorial". When I get to the verification stage in the tutorial and try to start the busybox deployment (https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/12-dns-addon.md), the pod status remains stuck at "ContainerCreating".

The kubelet log for the node that the pod supposed to run on shows these error messages:

```
failed to get sandbox image \"gcr.io/google_containers/pause:3.0\":
failed to pull image \"gcr.io/google_containers/pause:3.0\":
failed to pull image \"gcr.io/google_containers/pause:3.0\":
httpReaderSeeker: failed open: failed to do request:
Get https://storage.googleapis.com/artifacts.google-containers.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:f112334343777b75be77ec1f835e3bbbe7d7bd46e27b6a2ae35c6b3cfea0987c: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I added both of those domains to the list of insecure registries in /etc/docker/daemon.json:

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["gcr.io"],
  "insecure-registries" : ["googleapis.com"]
}
```

Docker is able to pull the image from the command line:

```
docker pull gcr.io/google_containers/pause:3.0
Trying to pull repository gcr.io/google_containers/pause ...
3.0: Pulling from gcr.io/google_containers/pause
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete
f11233434377: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:0d093c962a6c2dd8bb8727b661e2b5f13e9df884af9945b4cc7088d9350cd3ee
```

Any ideas why the kubelet is unable to pull the image?

Thanks,
TI

Comment: Were you able to figure this out because I am having the same issues with my kind cluster.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for this in `daemon.json` is

```
"insecure-registries" : ["gcr.io" , "googleapis.com"]
```

"Also depending of the registries you are accessing, you may have to perform a "`kubectl create secret docker-registry ...`" action as  explained [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)

Finally, you may have to define the certificate to `docker` by creating a new directory in `/etc/docker/certs.d` containing the certificates as explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/)

Comment: I tried suggestion #1 and #3, I'm pulling from a public repo and getting "man-in-the-middle'd" by a corporate CA. As OP, I can pull from docker outside of kind, but kind cannot pull the same images so I have to load them manually. Any other thoughts?