# Pull from private gitlab registry fails - x509: certificate is valid for ingress.local, not

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, containers, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to pull some container in my private gitlab registry but when I try I get the following error:

```
Failed to pull image "registry.mygitlab.com/name/container-backend:nginx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.mygitlab.com/v2/: x509: certificate is valid for ingress.local, not registry.mygitlab.com
```

In the deployment.yml I've added:

```
imagePullSecrets:
- name: registry-secret
```

and the `registry-secret` has been created with:

```
kubectl create \
—namespace=myns \
secret docker-registry registry2-secret \
--docker-server=registry.mygitlab.com \
--docker-username=myname \
--docker-password=mypassword
```

One month ago it worked and now it doesnt anymore.. and the credentials are correct :/

Comment: The error indicates your TLS certificate on the server is bad, not the login credential on the client.

Comment: The gitlab's certificate? Have you any idea how can I manage this?

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl.html

Answer (score 1):

Problem lays in TLS certificate on the server, not the login credential on the client.
Check if you have following record in  `daemon.json` file:

```
"insecure-registries" : ["registry.mygitlab.com"]
```

"Also depending of the registries you are accessing, you may have to perform a "`kubectl create secret docker-registry ...`" action as explained  [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/).
To create secret you should execute command:

```
$ kubectl create secret docker-registry registry-secret --docker-server=registry.gitlab.com --docker-username=<username> --docker-password=<password> --docker-email=<email
```

In `deployment.yaml` file you have used
secret named  `registry-secret` not
`registry2-secret` as you have used in command while creating secret -you had created wrong named secret.

Finally, you may have to define the certificate to  `docker`  by creating a new directory in  `/etc/docker/certs.d`  containing the certificates as explained  [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/).

Take a look: [x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48611756/kubelet-failed-to-pull-image-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority), [create-a-secret-that-holds-your-authorization-token](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-secret-that-holds-your-authorization-token).

Also take a look: [gitlab-tls](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/tls-self-signed.html).