# ImagePullBackOff: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, gitlab, ssl-certificate

I'm having trouble setting up k8s to use a private gitlab container registry. My gitlab is self-built, and the SSL certificate is also self-signed. both gitlab and gitlab container registry are outside of k8s.

I have only one node named k8s-m0. I can successfully pull the image from the registry on k8s-m0, but when I start the pod, always shows a error message about `ImagePullBackOff: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`：

```
$ kubectl describe pod compute-6bcb46f8df-fbm42 -n safe-swim
Name:         compute-6bcb46f8df-fbm42
Namespace:    safe-swim
Priority:     0
Node:         k8s-m0/192.168.0.107
Start Time:   Tue, 18 Jul 2023 15:49:49 +0800
Labels:       app=compute
              container=compute
              pod-template-hash=6bcb46f8df
Annotations:  cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: fbe6e6da4880c5aa05e06919b8ea5180d27f6e2b9fed0cbef14e990a9fa34603
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.233.79.76/32
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.233.79.76/32
Status:       Pending
IP:           10.233.79.76
IPs:
  IP:           10.233.79.76
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/compute-6bcb46f8df
Containers:
  compute-worker:
    Container ID:
    Image:          192.168.0.107:5050/k8s/test/compute-worker:lastest
    Image ID:
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/docker/certs.d/192.168.0.107:5050/ca.crt from ca-certs (ro)
      /etc/ssl/certs/192.168.0.107.crt from ca-certs (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-fh49q (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  ca-certs:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /etc/gitlab/ssl/192.168.0.107.crt
    HostPathType:
  kube-api-access-fh49q:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                     From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                    ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  9m46s                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned safe-swim/compute-6bcb46f8df-fbm42 to k8s-m0
  Warning  Failed     8m32s (x6 over 9m45s)   kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    8m17s (x4 over 9m45s)   kubelet            Pulling image "192.168.0.107:5050/k8s/test/compute-worker:lastest"
  Warning  Failed     8m17s (x4 over 9m45s)   kubelet            Failed to pull image "192.168.0.107:5050/k8s/test/compute-worker:lastest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "192.168.0.107:5050/k8s/test/compute-worker:lastest": failed to resolve reference "192.168.0.107:5050/k8s/test/compute-worker:lastest": failed to do request: Head "https://192.168.0.107:5050/v2/k8s/test/compute-worker/manifests/lastest": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
  Warning  Failed     8m17s (x4 over 9m45s)   kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    4m35s (x22 over 9m45s)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "192.168.0.107:5050/k8s/test/compute-worker:lastest"
```

I have tried:

1. Mount the self-signed ca.crt to the pod, refer to:

- [Pull from private gitlab registry fails - x509: certificate is valid for ingress.local, not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64959674/pull-from-private-gitlab-registry-fails-x509-certificate-is-valid-for-ingress)

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: compute-worker
    volumeMounts:
    - name: ca-certs
      mountPath: /etc/docker/certs.d/192.168.0.107:5050/ca.crt
      readOnly: true
    - name: ca-certs
      mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs/192.168.0.107.crt
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: ca-certs
    hostPath:
      path: /etc/gitlab/ssl/192.168.0.107.crt
```

I also verified my ca.crt (alias 192.168.0.107.crt) and I get `Verification: OK`

```
k8s-m0:/etc/gitlab/ssl $ echo | sudo openssl s_client -CAfile ${PWD}/192.168.0.107.crt -connect 192.168.0.107:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
Can't use SSL_get_servername
depth=0 C = TW, ST = Taiwan, L = Taipei, O = MyCompany, OU = fortuneai.app, CN = 192.168.0.107
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = TW, ST = Taiwan, L = Taipei, O = MyCompany, OU = my.app, CN = 192.168.0.107
   i:C = TW, ST = Taiwan, L = Taipei, O = MyCompany, OU = my.app, CN = 192.168.0.107
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Jul 13 12:01:23 2023 GMT; NotAfter: Jul 10 12:01:23 2033 GMT
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIOEiTCCSOMEINGSOMEINGSOMEINGSOMEINGSOMEING
...
G04SZ/aVlwPMTd+ODA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=C = TW, ST = Taiwan, L = Taipei, O = MyCompany, OU = my.app, CN = 192.168.0.107
issuer=C = TW, ST = Taiwan, L = Taipei, O = MyCompany, OU = my.app, CN = 192.168.0.107
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1721 bytes and written 373 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
DONE
```

2. Specify imagePullSecrets in Deployment, refer to https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43924#issuecomment-636836208

```
spec:
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: registry-credentials
  containers:
  - name: compute-worker
    image: 192.168.0.107:5050/k8s/test/compute-worker:lastest
```

I also verified my secret:

```
$ kubectl get secret -n safe-swim registry-credentials --output=yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: eyJhdXRocyI6eSOMEINGSOMEING
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-07-18T04:04:47Z"
  name: registry-credentials
  namespace: safe-swim
  resourceVersion: "2119916"
  uid: 83de0cc6-b502-4fd8-b6e6-cda9e72b7607
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson

$ kubectl get secret -n safe-swim registry-credentials --output="jsonpath={.data.\.dockerconfigjson}" | base64 --decode

{"auths":{"192.168.0.107:5050":{"username":"k8s-pull-image-account","password":"MY_PASSWORD","email":"zhenlong@my.app","auth":"azhzLXB1SOMEINGSOMEINGSOMEING=="}}}
```

3. let the k8s-m0 host trust this ca.crt credential:

```
sudo cp ./192.168.0.107.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/192.168.0.107.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

I also tried to forego verifying ca.crt, used two routes:

1. Add `"insecure-registries": ["192.168.0.107:5050"]` to the ~/.docker/daemon.json file on k8s-m0 and restart the docker service and restart docker service, refer to: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43924#issuecomment-290905127
2. use `kubectl apply -f ./k8s.yml -n safe-swim --insecure-skip-tls-verify`
3. ChatGPT gave me a crazy idea to use --insecure-registry when starting the pod:

```
spec:
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: registry-credentials
  containers:
  - name: compute-worker
    image: 192.168.0.107:5050/k8s/test/compute-worker:lastest
    env:
    - name: DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR
      value: ""
    command: ["sh", "-c"]
    args:
    - |
      dockerd-entrypoint.sh --insecure-registry=192.168.0.107:5050
```

None of this works, hopeless.

I have two questions:

1. How to fix this x509 error?
2. Why do the six methods mentioned above not work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you ping the document or steps for replicating the environment. I have gone through many references and all those links are redirecting to the same steps which you had already done.<br>